# Why does this method of downloading html form info as a string / .txt file remove all newlines from the file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html form with some inputs that I'd like the user to be able to download as a text file.

```html
<form onsubmit="download()" action=''>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="text" id="age">
    <input type="text" id ="sex">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Download</button>
</form>
```

The javascript to download the file is as follows

```
function download() {
    var _text = makeString();
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(_text));
    element.setAttribute('download', 'example.txt');

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function makeString() {
    return "Name: " + $("#name").val() + "\nAge: " + $("#age").val() + "\nSex: " + $("#sex").val();
}
```

If I enter into these inputs the values `John`, `25`, and `Male`, and hit download, I end up with  a file that looks like
`Name: JohnAge: 25Sex: Male`.  What's happening to the newlines here? And what can I do to keep them in the file? Thanks!

The part of my code that creates the text file and downloads it is from an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server) post, which is at least 4 years old. There may very well be a better way to do this and I'm open to suggestions on that front as well.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Windows files use `\r\n` for newlines, whereas `\n` is for Unix/Mac/basically anything else. Browsers support `\n` but Windows as an OS doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `encodeURIComponent`, you also need to use `\r` for adding a new line in your string, otherwise `\n` will be ignored (for Windows (and many old OS) code for the end of the line - 2 characters, `\r\n`, in that order).

Two different characters.

- `\n` is used as a terminator in Unix text files.
- `\r` is used as a terminator for the end of a line in Mac text files.
- `\r\ n` (i.e., both) are used to terminate lines in Windows and DOS
  text files.

Two different characters for different operating systems. It also plays a role in data transmitted via `TCP / IP`, which requires the use of `\r\n`.

```
 function makeString() {
        return "Name: " + $("#name").val() + "\r\nAge: " + $("#age").val() + "\r\nSex: " + $("#sex").val();
    }
```

I also recomend to use `return false;` in `onsubmit` fuction to prevent the submit action.

```
function download() {


    var _text = makeString();
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(_text));
    element.setAttribute('download', 'example.txt');

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I'm sort of confused as to why I never had to do this when manipulating strings in python and java (as far as I know). Does js just not automatically change it to the correct newline chars because of its heavy use in data transmission, or is there another reason?

Comment: I don't want to give an inaccurate answer, but I think it can be related to the browser which runs the javascript. Java and python has a pre installed compiler in your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

For windows, new line is recognized as \r\n. Notepad will not be able to understand \n alone although notepad++ will.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% on what's going on, but you trying using "\r" instead of "\n"...

[image]

Comment: Don't use `\r` exclusively.  That hasn't been in-use in many years.

Comment: Though "\n" was working too in CodeSandbox. When I used both "\n\r", there was two line breaks (too many). Either way, you should give it a try (in a non-permanent way) to see what you get.

Comment: `\r` is what old Apple systems used.  `\n` is what current OS X, Linux, most everybody uses.  `\r\n` is what Windows uses.  `\n\r` isn't a thing, so if you put that in on your Mac, your text editor is being nice by accepting `\n` and old-style `\r` separately.